# Installing linecache19 for Ruby 1.9.2 via rvm

Tags: rubygems, rvm, ruby-1.9.2, linecache

I am having a problem with installing linecache19(dependency of ruby-debug19) for ruby 1.9.2

Here is my term output

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
$ rvm exec gem install linecache19 --backtrace
gem install linecache19 --backtrace

rvm 1.6.20 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

ERROR:  Error installing linecache19:
    linecache19 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
ERROR:  Error installing linecache19:
    linecache19 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

The last command hangs forever until interrupted with ^C.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You may be having the same problem as I was. When I ran `bundle install` I got the error:

```
Installing linecache19 (0.5.12) with native extensions
/Users/joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:552:in `rescue in block in build_extensions':
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/Users/joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

From http://isitruby19.com/linecache19 I found that this worked:

```
gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and tried the commands but it didn't help without a forceful installation of linecache19, so all who face with similar errors check my working solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700828/installing-gems-without-rvm-as-root-with-explicit-version-of-ruby/7781550#7781550

Comment: BTW I am now using https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger. It is "A fork of ruby-debug(19) that works on 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 and installs easily for rvm/rbenv rubies."

Comment: Same problem on 1.9.3-head + mac os x 10.7 lion, just use $rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-head will do the job.

Comment: I had a similar error with debugger-linecache and your --with-ruby-include solved it, for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (linecache19 hangs forever/indefinitely) when using rbenv on OS X Lion.  I found the solution was to install Ruby with OpenSSL option, like this:

```
rbenv install 1.9.2-p290 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local
reben rehash
rbenv global 1.9.2-p290
```

Now, you can run this and it'll install fine:

```
gem install ruby-debug19
```

Hope that helps someone.  Hat tip to [adrpac's gist](https://gist.github.com/1232707).

Answer (score 1):

`rvm exec` attempts to [run the given command over every version of Ruby installed](http://beginrescueend.com/set/exec/). Do you have another version installed other than 1.9.2 (including the system default)? If so, it's likely this version that's failing.

If you `rvm use 1.9.2`, you don't need to do anything special to have commands execute in the context of Ruby 1.9.2--RVM sets up the environment when you run `use`. Just do a `gem install linecache19 --backtrace`.

Answer (score 1):

You can even do something along the lines of

```
rvm 1.9.2@global exec 'gem install linecache19 -- --with-ruby-include="${rvm_path}/src/${rvm_env_string//@*}"'
```

You can then do something like this to apply the install against all your 1.9.2 rubies.

```
for ver in $(ls $rvm_path/rubies | grep 1.9.2 | sed s/ruby-//g | sed s/\\///g); do rvm $ver@global exec 'gem install linecache19 -- --with-ruby-include="${rvm_path}/src/${rvm_env_string//@*}"'
```

That command will walk through each 1.9.2 ruby returned from the $(ls ..) command and apply your rvm command to each of them.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
rvm @global gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/$(rvm tools strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment

```
 #gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Then bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was running `gem` under `rvm`, using exec:

```
'sudo rvm exec gem install ruby-debug19'
'sudo rvm exec gem install linecache19'
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the source of the ruby files under rvm worked for me

```
gem install linecache19  -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.2-head/
```