# Error installing linecache19

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, linecache

I've been trying to run `bundle install`. What follows is a series of commands I entered and the relevant snippets of the error messages.

```
bundle update
```

An error occurred while installing linecache (0.46), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install linecache -v '0.46'` succeeds before bundling.

```
gem install linecache -v '0.46'
```

Can't handle 1.9.x yet

```
gem install linecache19
```

checking for vm_core.h... no

and finally:

```
gem install linecache19 -- --with-ruby-include=/opt/t/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194

ERROR:  Error installing linecache19:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/t/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-ruby-include=/opt/t/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for version.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling trace_nums.c
In file included from trace_nums.c:21:
/opt/t/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194/vm_core.h:311:5: error: unknown type name 'rb_event_hook_t'; did you mean 'rb_event_flag_t'?
    rb_event_hook_t *event_hooks;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    rb_event_flag_t
/opt/t/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1602:23: note: 'rb_event_flag_t' declared here
typedef unsigned long rb_event_flag_t;
                      ^
In file included from trace_nums.c:21:
/opt/t/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194/vm_core.h:477:5: error: unknown type name 'rb_event_hook_t'; did you mean 'rb_event_flag_t'?
    rb_event_hook_t *event_hooks;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    rb_event_flag_t
/opt/t/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1602:23: note: 'rb_event_flag_t' declared here
typedef unsigned long rb_event_flag_t;
                      ^
trace_nums.c:61:25: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    len = strlen(token) - 1;
        ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [trace_nums.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/t/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/linecache19-0.5.12 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/t/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
```

Comment: POSSIBLE DUPLICATE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650567/installing-linecache19-for-ruby-1-9-2-via-rvm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

force the Gemfile to use these version

```
gem 'linecache19', '0.5.13', :path => "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/linecache19-0.5.13/"
```

and then `bundle install`

Comment: This works too with the latest (until today) ruby version: 

> gem 'linecache19', '0.5.12', :path => "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/".